# Execute method on child component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent component and a child component. I want to be able to call some child method on the child component from some method on the parent component.
Is there a way to get a reference to the child component instance on the parent's class and call child's public methods?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-component'
})
@View({
    template: `<div>child</div>`
})
class ChildComponent{
    constructor () {

    }

    doChildEvent () {
        //  some child event
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'parent-component'
})
@View({
    template: `
        <child-component #child></child-component>
    `,
    directives: [
        ChildComponent
    ]
})
class ParentComponent {
    private child:ChildComponent;

    constructor () {

    }

    onSomeParentEvent() {
        this.child.doChildEvent();
    }
}
```

I tried putting a hash on the child in template and referencing it in the class but no success.

Comment: `#child` - these local template variables do not become properties on the component (as you discovered).  I can't find anything in the documentation about their scope (and I don't feel like looking at the source code).  It seems their scope is limited to the template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what [`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewChild-var.html) is for:

```
//don't forget to import ViewChild

class ParentComponent {
    @ViewChild(ChildComponent) private child:ChildComponent;

    constructor () {
       //this.child is undefined because constructor is called before AfterViewInit
    }

    onSomeParentEvent() {
        //this.child contains the reference you're looking for 
        this.child.doChildEvent();
    }
}
```

Assuming `onSomeParentEvent` is fired after [`AfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/AfterViewInit-interface.html),
`this.child` will contain a reference to the child component.

Comment: Just what I was looking for!